# Identifying coordinate system of Wetterzentrale maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, georeferencing, arctic

I'm trying to georeference two maps from wetterzentrale in ArcGIS Desktop.

In what coordinate system are those maps created?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140838/wetterzentrale-maps-georeferencing-coordinate-system#comment203871_140838) a guess might be:

> north pole-centered stereographic with a central meridian/longitude of origin around -20

Otherwise I think you will be best to try and contact the author(s) of the maps.